# 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. json file deleted

Tags: html, reactjs, json, output

the errror is 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ive tried

```
npm install
npm install react-scripts --save
npm i -g react-scripts
```

https://github.com/mareyam/Complete-Maryam-s-Restaurant
i uploaded this code on github without .json file
now im trying to donwnload and use it but cant because ,json file ive lost. ive tried using json file from anothr project but not working

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `create-react-app` to build this project. Run the command, cd into the directory then start the app.

```
npx create-react-app name_of_app
cd name_of_app
npm start
```

This will be good enough for development, and you can add all your components into the `src/` folder.  [Here's](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) the documentation for how to start building react web apps.

To get the production build (which I think is what you're trying to go for), run `npm run build` which will save the build in the `build/` folder.

Any time you use a different machine, just pull the project from github and run `npm i`. I'm assuming that you were talking about the `package.json` file. This shouldn't be a big deal if you set everything up correctly.